# Can't bind to 'appendTo' since it isn't a known property of p-confirmPopup

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a PrimeNG component I would like to append to the parent div, but it seems to always be appending to the body.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmationService, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { ConfirmPopupModule } from 'primeng/confirmpopup';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prime-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ConfirmPopupModule],
  providers: [ConfirmationService, MessageService],
  template: `<div #appendMe>appendme</div>
    <p-confirmPopup [appendTo]="appendMe"></p-confirmPopup>
    <button (click)="confirmationService.confirm({ message: 'test' })">
      open confirm
    </button> `,
  styleUrl: './prime-button.component.css',
})
export class PrimeButtonComponent {
  constructor(
    public confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    public messageService: MessageService
  ) {}
}
```

I understand that one can use the property [appendTo] using a template variable and target the corresponding element as the one to receive the appended element.

With square brackets around appendTo, I get the following error:
`Can't bind to 'appendTo' since it isn't a known property of 'p-confirmPopup'.`

Without square brackets around appendTo, the element still appends to the HTML body.

As you can see, I've imported ConfirmPopupModule into the standalone component both in the decorator and in the imports. The property appendTo doesn't seem to exist on the class ConfirmPopup defined in the confirmpopup.d.ts file found in the PrimeNG node_modules folder.

How can I make this popup element append to the parent div?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the `$event` and then set the `target` property to `event.target as EventTarget` That should bind it to the button that calls it.

Take a look at the examples in the documentation.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmationService, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { ConfirmPopupModule } from 'primeng/confirmpopup';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prime-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ConfirmPopupModule],
  providers: [ConfirmationService, MessageService],
  template: `
      <p-confirmPopup</p-confirmPopup>
      <button (click)="confirm($event)">open confirm</button> 
  `,
  styleUrl: './prime-button.component.css',
})
export class PrimeButtonComponent {
  constructor(
    public confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    public messageService: MessageService
  ) {}

  confirm(event) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      target: event.target as EventTarget,
      message: 'test message',
      accept: () => console.log('accept'),
      reject: () => console.log('reject'),
    });
  }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you can have just one set of `<p-confirmPopup></p-confirmPopup>` tags in a parent component (or the root page.) Each button, will then have popup attached to it when clicked.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Do you have any tips for resources to check out if I get stuck again? The docs at https://primeng.org/confirmpopup weren't very helpful, but perhaps I just didn't know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

The `ConfirmPopup` does not have a property `[appendTo]` defined in the [api definitions](https://primeng.org/confirmpopup). Instead go for `ConfirmDialog` component which does have `[appendTo]` defined in the [api defintion](https://primeng.org/confirmdialog)

#### [appendTo](https://primeng.org/confirmdialog#api.confirmdialog.props.appendTo)

> Target element to attach the dialog, valid values are "body" or a local ng-template variable of another element (note: use binding with brackets for template variables, e.g. [appendTo]="mydiv" for a div element having #mydiv as variable name).